# Fragment Slide Webviews

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview

Im trying to add webviews to the pages that are available when the user displays the menu.  The pages were created using fragments but when I add the webviews I get an error that wants me to change  fragment "changeFragment(new CalenderFragment());" in MenuActivity cannot be applied to "packagename.CalenderFragment".  Any idea how to solve this?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.special.ResideMenu.ResideMenu;
import com.special.ResideMenu.ResideMenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MenuActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ResideMenu resideMenu;
    private MenuActivity mContext;
    private ResideMenuItem itemHome;
    private ResideMenuItem itemProfile;
    private ResideMenuItem itemCalendar;
    private ResideMenuItem itemSettings;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContext = this;
        setUpMenu();
        changeFragment(new HomeFragment());
        Parse.initialize(this, "7JLdMxO2NWiXQ5uSGQWfaFiUn8M9uV2wmpjUhU8c", "IHe5AAS1WPayYB08zNSmM89d81lx842H1VVHYcHh");
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MenuActivity.class);
    }

    private void setUpMenu() {

        // attach to current activity;
        resideMenu = new ResideMenu(this);
        resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.menu_background);
        resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);
        resideMenu.setMenuListener(menuListener);
        //valid scale factor is between 0.0f and 1.0f. leftmenu'width is 150dip. 
        resideMenu.setScaleValue(0.6f);

        // create menu items;
        itemHome     = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_home,     "Home");
        itemProfile  = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_profile,  "Profile");
        itemCalendar = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_calendar, "Calendar");
        itemSettings = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.icon_settings, "Settings");

        itemHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemSettings.setOnClickListener(this);

        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemHome, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemProfile, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemCalendar, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(itemSettings, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);

        // You can disable a direction by setting ->
        // resideMenu.setSwipeDirectionDisable(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);

        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_left_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.title_bar_right_menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resideMenu.openMenu(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return resideMenu.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == itemHome){
            changeFragment(new HomeFragment());
        }else if (view == itemProfile){
            changeFragment(new ProfileFragment());
        }else if (view == itemCalendar){
            changeFragment(new CalendarFragment());
        }else if (view == itemSettings){
            changeFragment(new SettingsFragment());
        }

        resideMenu.closeMenu();
    }



    private ResideMenu.OnMenuListener menuListener = new ResideMenu.OnMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void openMenu() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is opened!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void closeMenu() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Menu is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment){
        resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();
    }

    // What good method is to access resideMenu？
    public ResideMenu getResideMenu(){
        return resideMenu;
    }
}
```

Logcat/Error

```
Error:Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) C:\Users\jorda_000\Desktop\MASTER\AndroidResideMenu-master\.idea\workspace.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\jorda_000\Desktop\MASTER\AndroidResideMenu-master\.idea\workspace.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.JDOMUtil.loadDocument(JDOMUtil.java:340)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadRootElement(JpsLoaderBase.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsLoaderBase.loadComponents(JpsLoaderBase.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadFromDirectory(JpsProjectLoader.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:71)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: post CalendarFragment

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I changed the "new" to post but now its saying that it expects a method.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you post the logcar/error for me to check.